# I want to remove the boundary using opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I have this original image:

[image]

then I have applied the following code to

1. Converted the Original image to HSV image
2. Then using `cv2.findContours()` I have made a list containing all the contours.
3. Then i have removed all the contours of area less than 30.
4. Then I got the following image:

[image]

What I want is to remove the boundary from the resulting image it is of no use (outer boundary of leaf).I only need the inner patches of the leaf.
This is the code i used.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('Apple___Blackrot30.JPG')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)     
lower_gr = np.array([25,0,0])
upper_gr = np.array([90,255,255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_gr,upper_gr)
mask=~mask   
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask = mask)
blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(res,9,75,75)
im2,cont,_ = cv2.findContours(mask,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
areas = [cv2.contourArea(each_conts) for each_conts in cont]
cont_counter = 0
for each_conts in areas:
    if each_conts < 30:
        cv2.fillPoly(im2, pts =[cont[cont_counter]], color=(0,0,0))
    if each_conts > 1024:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, cont[cont_counter], 0, (255,255,255), -1)    
    cont_counter+=1

cv2.imshow('cn',im2)
```

Comment: Hard to understand, what results you expect

Comment: I want to remove the boundaries of the leaf in the resultant output image as i don't require it

Comment: A color threshold based on the original image maybe? If it is for this example in particular, you can threshold your image to only keep the yellow/brown parts, and then you apply your edge detector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the concept of [hierarchy of contours](https://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html) to solve this problem. But there is a caveat, all your images must be the same as the one in the question.

I just added some additional stuff to your code.

**Code:**

```
img2 = img.copy()
im2, cont, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

l = []
for e, h in enumerate(hierarchy[0]):
    #print (e, h[3])
    if h[3] == -1:
        l.append(e)

for i in l:
    if cv2.contourArea(cont[i]) < 1000:   
        cv2.drawContours(img2, [cont[i]], -1, (0, 255, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow('img2', img2)
```

**Result:**

[image]

`hierarchy` returns an array expressing the parent-child relationship of contours. As per the documentation link,

> it as an array of four values : **[Next, Previous, First_Child, Parent]**.

In the `hierarchy` array I scanned the `Parent` column (4th column) to see whether it has no parent contours (`-1`) and drew them

Comment: I am getting a error "nonetype object is not subscriptable" for the line    " for e, h in enumerate(hierarchy[0]):"

Comment: @ParasKumarLangyan Check if `hierarchy` is empty

Comment: How can I do that I have a very big database of images. I tried various methods like 'len(hierarchy[0])== 0 ' but it is giving me the same error. The problem is I have very large dataset and I am even trying to like deleting the image but it isn't working. I tried printing the image name but what it does is just give me this  error message to me

Comment: The error shows if no contour is found in the image. After this line `im2, cont, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)` check if contours are present by `if cont != None:` and then go to the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you only need the inner spots inside a leaf.

1. Segment using the otsu algorithm
2. apply the flood-fill operation to ensure you capture all leaf pixels
3. Extract only the inner contour
   All can simply be done using opencv below are the codes:

> 

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def flood_fill_binary(binary):
    hh = binary.shape[0]
    ww = binary.shape[1]
    xx = 10
    yy = 10
    black = [0,0,0]
    binary = cv2.copyMakeBorder(binary,10,10,10,10,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=black)
    im_floodfill = binary.copy()
    h, w = binary.shape[:2]
    mask = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8)
    cv2.floodFill(im_floodfill, mask, (0,0), 255)
    im_floodfill_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(im_floodfill)
    im_out = binary | im_floodfill_inv
    crop_og = im_out[yy:yy+hh,xx:xx+ww]
    return crop_og

def leaf_spots_detector(image):
    image = image.astype('uint8')
    hh = image.shape[0]
    ww = image.shape[1]
    xx = 10
    yy = 10
    #kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
    grayed_image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, segmented = cv2.threshold(grayed_image,0, 255, 
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    segmented = flood_fill_binary(segmented)
    segmented = cv2.copyMakeBorder(segmented,xx,xx,yy,yy,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value= 
    [0,0,0])
    major = cv2.__version__.split('.')[0]
    if major == '3':
        ret, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(segmented, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
   cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    else:
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(segmented, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
   cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        print(hierarchy.shape)
    image_external = np.zeros(segmented.shape, segmented.dtype)
    for i in range(1,len(contours)):
         #if hierarchy[0][i][3] == -1:
        cv2.drawContours(image_external, contours, i,(225,255,255), -1)
    image_external = image_external[yy:yy+hh,xx:xx+ww]
    #image_external = cv2.dilate(image_external,kernel,iterations = 1)
    return image_external

image = cv2.imread('image/path.png')
leaf_spots = leaf_spots_detector(image)
cv2.imshow("detected spots", leaf_spots)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindow()
```